# How to go to tab activity by pressing a button in main activity?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I have main.xml contain a button, and tab.xml containing the  tabs fragments, does anyone know how to move to the tab activity by pressing the button in the main.xml ?

Comment: The best practices is to use onClickListener for your button in your main.java file.

Comment: can you tell me an example (sample of the code) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.snehpandya.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
                startActivity(mIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```